# check if selected index changed from specific value

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Listbox that allows you to select different menus. Say my Listbox contains 3 indexes. 1, 2, and 3. Index 3 is special and does things that effect 1 and 2. I want to do a specific action if the selected index changes from 3 to any other index.

Basically I want the following.

```
if (selectedindex was = 3)
{
//Do stuff
}
```

Edit: I wanted to clarify a little bit. My listbox contains 3 things you can select, see below. Bare in mind that the numbers are used for my example.

[image]

So, if I click on 3, then click on 1 or 2, I want it to do a very specific thing.

Comment: Store the previously selected index in a variable and compare?

Comment: *Contains 3 Indexes* means that you have 3 Items or that you have 3 Items that contain Values from 1 to 3? If you have 3 Items, the Indexes are in the range `0-2`.

Comment: @Jimi I made an edit to clarify what I was trying to convey. Sorry, should have done that when posting.

Comment: You have to specify exactly what the ListBox Items contain. *I have a Listbox that allows you to select different menus*: Menus? It's important that the type of the data stored in Controls is really clear. It's also very important to specify (possibly in code), what is the DataSource of a Control. Or, if the Control is filled adding Items manually. This whole procedure must be in the question. Any possible answer depends on this, plus a clear definition of what the expected outcome is. I.e., what is the *very specific thing*. It'll become pretty clear when data type and datasource are defined.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class variable to hold the previously selected value for the list.  When the form gets created, set the selected item for the list and initialize the previously selected value.  Add a changed event handler to the list and use it to maintain the previously selected value.  Use the previously selected value to react as appropriate for your problem - in this case whenever the user changes from "3".

Answer (score -1):

Assuming this is a ListBox_SelectionChanged event, you can do it this way.

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(var item in e.RemovedItems)
    {
        if (item.ToString() == 3)
        {
            //do things
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is tagged WinForms, not WPF. I also have some doubts about this comparison: `item.ToString() == 3`